# Issue with icon placement inside navigation menu bar and its header's placement

Tags: html, css, header, icons, alignment

I am having an issue with formatting my social media icons in the navigation menu bar that I created. What I have found is that because I have centered the header in the navigation menu bar, it covers up the whole center of the menu bar and does not allow the Facebook icon or Instagram icon to be placed and centered inside the bar.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel = "icon" href="LogoBlack.PNG" type="image/SVG">
    <style>
        body {margin:0;}
        .Header {
            position: fixed;

            width: 100%;
            background-color: #000000;
            height: 70px;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="Header" id="myHeader">
    <a class = "headerLogo">
        <a href="file:///C:/Noah's%20stuff/Home.html" ><h1 style="color:white; font-family: Verdana; font-style: italic; font-size: x-large;
        text-align: center;">Header</h1></a>
        <style>
            a{text-decoration: none}
        </style>

    </a>

    <a class = "Facebook" style = "padding-left: 1000px;">
        <img src = "facebook-3-xxl.png">
    </a>
    <a class = "Instagram" style = "padding-left: 30px">
        <img src = "instagram-32.png">
    </a>
</div>
</body>
<body>
```

Here is my updated code, that is still dealing with the icons not aligned to the center of the menu bar

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel = "icon" href="LogoBlack.PNG" type="image/SVG">
    <style>
        body {margin:0;}
        .Header {
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #000000;
            text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 50%;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="Header" id="myHeader">
    <a class = "headerLogo">
        <a href="file:///C:/Noah's%20stuff/Home.html" ><h1 style="color:white; font-family: Verdana; font-style: italic; font-size: x-large;
        text-align: center;">Header</h1></a>
        <style>
            a{text-decoration: none}
        </style>

    </a>

    <a class = "Facebook" style = "margin-left: 50%; margin-bottom: 500px">
        <img src = "facebook-3-xxl.png">
    </a>
    <a class = "Instagram" style = "margin-left: 2%">
        <img src = "instagram-32.png">
    </a>
</div>
</body>
<body>
```

Comment: What I am finding is that because it is a header, it is taking up the whole space for where it is aligned, so I am not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the icons to be centered rather use `text-align:center;` on their parent element (which is `.Header`) than aligning them with padding.

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel = "icon" href="LogoBlack.PNG" type="image/SVG">
    <style>
        body {margin:0;}
        .Header {
            position: fixed;

            width: 100%;
            height:70px;
            background-color: #000000;
            text-align:right;
        }
        .socialmedia {
          position:fixed;
          right:0;
          top:35px;
          transform:translate(0,-50%);
         }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="Header" id="myHeader">
    <a class = "headerLogo">
        <a href="file:///C:/Noah's%20stuff/Home.html" ><h1 style="color:white; font-family: Verdana; font-style: italic; font-size: x-large;
        text-align: center;">Header</h1></a>
        <style>
            a{text-decoration: none}
        </style>

    </a>
  <div class="socialmedia">
    <a class = "Facebook">
        <img src = "https://images.seeklogo.net/2016/09/facebook-icon-preview-1.png" width="50px" height="50px">
    </a>
    <a class = "Instagram">
        <img src = "https://images.seeklogo.net/2016/06/Instagram-logo.png"  width="50px" height="50px">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
<body>
```

Comment: It only centered the icons, I want them on the right side of the menu but, also inside the menu, as of right now, they are not.

Comment: How do you want the social media links to be displayed ?

Comment: I wrote it in my comment above

Comment: You can use `text-align:right;` then. They weren't in the header because the header had a fixed height to 70px.

Comment: So its inside the navigation menu bar and aligned to the right correctly but its not centered with the header

Comment: You'd have to put a wrapper around the elements and position them fixed to the right or float them. See code snippet above.

Comment: It's all fixed, I also wanted to put the Youtube icon next to the Instagram icon and I'm wondering where you found those icons that you used?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136796/discussion-between-woulduracler-and-noah-tanenholtz).